# Master/Secondary Password for Windows Domain Users

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windowsdomainaccount

We have a really small setup but for the sake of keeping everything centralized we have a domain.

Occasionally managers will need to send email out as somebody else if they are not in the office, is it possible to add a secondary password or a master password to everyone's account through a group policy? That way if needed we could logon as that user and send out an email. Obviously it seems a little unusual but the password would only really be for one or two mangers. Not everybody.

I was thinking just giving passwords out to everyone and keeping track of them and not allowing them to change them, but seems bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You can configure Exchange (if you're using that) to allow people to send mail as or on behalf of other users.